# Output array with foreach with PHP

Tags: php

I created in Array and everytime i output it, there is only one row shown. I want to show every row.
Here is the code:

```
//Input in Array
$_SESSION['warenkorb'][] = array('warenkorb_id' => $_POST['a_id_warenkorb'], 'buchtyp' => $_POST ['buchtyp'], 'menge' => $_POST['menge']);

//Array Output
    foreach ($_SESSION['warenkorb'] as $index => $inhalt);
            {
            echo $inhalt['warenkorb_id'];
            echo $inhalt['buchtyp'];
            echo $inhalt['menge'];
            }
```

I hope someone can help me :)
Lukas

Comment: There was an error in line 5 at the end. `);` is incorrect.

Comment: There is only one row in your output. You have no <br>, and only one row in $_SESSION array. https://3v4l.org/oX82V

Comment: Other than the `;` at the end of your foreach line it will work. If you are expecting values from other pages - are you initiating the session on each page? You must include `session_start();`.

Comment: Still i am not geting what you want... !!! because with the same code out put is correct. the all array key can be echo properly. **With semicolon**

Comment: @luki512 see my answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon(";") at end of foreach.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['warenkorb'] as $index => $inhalt)
```

Comment: the semicolon is not an issue , i think.

Comment: semicolon is the issue (;)

Comment: Check out this example - with and without a semicolon - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/270e63395435833806102b6a85d471fc19099556

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f951bd72501ac3566a99cba1453731cfd5737034

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b69b3053933962598b0783ab710002ee3af3a26e

Answer (score 0):

1. Page load only once so you get only one array
2. There is only one array so you it disolays one row only
3. Add `session_start();` at start of file

Try This

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['warenkorb'][] = array('warenkorb_id' => $_POST['a_id_warenkorb'], 'buchtyp' => $_POST ['buchtyp'], 'menge' => $_POST['menge']);

//Array Output
    foreach ($_SESSION['warenkorb'] as $index => $inhalt);
            {
            echo $inhalt['warenkorb_id'];
            echo $inhalt['buchtyp'];
            echo $inhalt['menge'];
            }
?>
```